# Draw objects at a minimum of one pixel wide

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, 3d, unity-game-engine

I want to draw a very thin object and it disappears because of aliasing. Understandable of course. But I would like to ascertain that this object is on my screen. For at least 1 pixel wide.

The thin object is not a simple OpenGL line, it is an actual 3D object. Is there a way to project this object to the screen or something to make it always visible, regardless of aliasing problems? (See image)

I am using Unity3D, but have also access to simple OpenGL functions.

[image: up: what I have, down: what I want]

Comment: Maybe you should compute the projected bounding box of your object before rendering it, and if smaller than a given value, render a simple pixel sized square instead.

Comment: Alternatively, calculate the screen space position of the object centre and render a big red arrow pointing towards it as an overlay :-).

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution which will make all sorts of objects visible for at least one pixel, or more specific, say, that this particular object (which is always parallel to the ground) is visible? Anyways you could just draw over the line manually (or a square or whatever, like Nicolas suggested), or maybe render your object to texture first and run some filter on it? (which would find  the missing pixels and fill them in.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not draw a line and then draw the object on top?